# How change bytes on packet before send

Tags: delphi

how can i modify some bytes on packet before send?
i'm doing this code:

```
function WSASendHookProc(s: TSocket; var lpBuffers; dwBufferCount: DWORD; var lpNumberOfBytesSent: DWORD; dwFlags: DWORD; lpOverlapped: LPWSAOVERLAPPED; lpCompletionRoutine: LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE): Integer; stdcall;
var
  DataBuffer    : PChar;
  DataS         : TSocket;
begin
  Result := 0; (here already tried call the TramplineWSASend, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent and still the same thing)
  DataS  := s;

  GetMem(DataBuffer, Result);
  try
    CopyMemory(DataBuffer, @lpBuffers, Result);
    //word(pointer(DataBuffer)^) := word(pointer(DataBuffer)^);
    CopyMemory(@lpBuffers, DataBuffer, Result);
  finally
    FreeMem(DataBuffer);
  end;

  Result := TrampolineWSASend(s, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount, lpNumberOfBytesSent, dwFlags, lpOverlapped, lpCompletionRoutine);
end;
```

but on this line `//word(pointer(DataBuffer)^) := word(pointer(DataBuffer)^);` if remove the // application crash without show any error.
But now if i don't remove the // application works fine, but i can't modify the bytes.

Comment: *".. can't modify the bytes."* - What bytes? You don't have any, you're requesting 0 bytes from GetMem.

Comment: i've changed to TrampolineCallback or dwBufferCount or lpNumberOfBytesSent but still the same problem.

Comment: Should most likely be 'PWord(DataBuffer)^ := NewWord'

Comment: the same, application crash.

Comment: It would better to show real code with guaranteed non-zero DataBuffer size

Comment: @FredS that's the exact same thing

Comment: So you already tried other things that didn't work out.. What do you think are the chances of modifying memory that doesn't exist? Or is this a philosophical question?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz if don't are to help please don't post.

Comment: Well, that comment should convince you that your current approach cannot work. And perhaps encourage you to go back to the documentation to find out where the payload actually lives. Likewise MBo's comment should encourage you to post a MCVE. Comments are helpful, it's up to you to make use of them or dismiss them.

Comment: I'm doing this hook on an server application, who i need crypt the informations who are send, and on client application i've hooked recv api. I know have informations walking between applications, i just need crypt it. These both applications don't are coded by me, it's from a game.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GetMem(DataBuffer, dwBufferCount);`
That will allocate the memory necessary for the buffer.

Then you Copy the buffer:

```
CopyMemory(DataBuffer, lpBuffers, dwBufferCount);
```

Now you can edit the memory from `DataBuffer`, for example:

```
PWord(DataBuffer)^ := Word(Your word value here);
```

Then in `TrampolineWSASend` you need to replace `lpBuffers` to `DataBuffer`.